# Ubuntu 20.04: File Manager (Nautilus) crashes on startup

Tags: nautilus, crash

When I start file manager it immediately crashes.  Log entries follow:

17:39:55 gnome-disks: Error loading icon starred-symbolic: XML parse error: malformed data: URL (rsvg-error-quark, 0)

17:39:49 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'

How do I clear the issue?

Many Thanks

Chris C

Comment: In passing,  I have tried moving .config/nautilus out of the way to no effect.  Nautilus worked when I first installed 20.04, but I was (if I recall correctly) doing something on the local network when it first failed....